# Can I use CSS attribute values in javascript in rails?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Say I have a .box class in CSS:

```
.box
{
   height: 50px;
}
```

Now, I use javascript to allow the user to expand the box and make it small again. Currently I have the value of the box height (ie 50 px) hardcoded in javascript.

I'm wondering if there's a way where my javascript code can access the height attribute of the box class as defined in CSS so that if I change the height in CSS to 100px for example, I wouldn't have to go and manually change the corresponding variable in javascript

btw I'm using rails3 and jquery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With jQuery it's pretty easy, although you have to use some trickery to get around the fact that jQuery's [`height()`](http://api.jquery.com/height/) function spits back `50px` instead of `50`.

Just for getting the object's height, try this:

`$(".box").height();`

It doesn't succumb to the issue I stated above. The following example does, and fixes it. It can also be used for every other CSS attribute.

`var boxHeight = $(".box").css("height").replace("px", "");`

Docs [here](http://api.jquery.com/css/).

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("mybox").style.height = myheight + "px";
```

Comment: What do you mean? You can call this more than once.

Comment: Isn't that exactly what you want?